# How to query with "greater than" in mongoDB with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following piece of code that is supposed to return all entries with values of "usnchanged" that are above 31000. However, it returns no results whatsoever.

```
<?php
$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');

$filter = ['usnchanged' => ['$gt' => 31000]];
$options = ['projection' => ['_usnchanged' => 31000],];

$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);

$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('student.user', $query);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    //var_dump($doc);
    print_r($doc);
}

?>
```

Note, I am searching in the proper database and collection. Normal queries work such as "name" => "Joe Schmoe".

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What does driver documentation say about this?

Comment: Can we see a sample document?